# Subdivide a part of an object while avoiding tri's

Tags: subdivision-surface, topology

Say I have this base mesh:

[image]

I'd like to make the abs more defined, so I use `Edge` > `Subdivision` on them. However, it creates lots of tri's:

[image]

Is there a better way to add more geometry while keeping them all quads?